# Is it possible to program an iOS 8 app in pure Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

Is it possible to write apps in pure Objective C in iOS 8 (not using Swift at all), because I don't feel like learning Swift for the moment?

Comment: One question per question, please, and your second question is really too broad and vague for SO.

Comment: 1) Yes, it is.  2) No.

Comment: I updated my old app and built it with the iOS 8 SDK, and it's written purely in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes surely you can do to do that select new project and select Objective C in place of Swift

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes. In fact I recommend you use Objective-c for the time being. Swift isn't finished yet and it will surely change over the time, until it matures. Also, concerning the iOS Apis they are written in Objective-C and adapted to work in Swift. There is a great inconsistency between data types used by the iOS Swift Apis(they use the Objective-c data types instead of the native Swift ones). From my experience (I started developing and learning swift this month), it's best to stick to Objective-c for now.

Comment: swift IS finished in the sense that it is at [1.0](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=14). Yes, it will change and well so will/did Objective-C. I think the biggest change between the two is shifting paradigms from a OOP, dynamic language to a OOP/generic (and kinda functional) strongly typed language

Comment: I know that the official version is 1.0 but it surely doesn't look finished to me. I

Comment: oh yeah, it is early days yet. I also wanted to mention that there is a lot of legacy (1 million apps) written in Objective-c as well as countless libraries.

Comment: I like the swift approach, but it will take some time until we can use it at its full power when developing apps.

Comment: @Dănuț Mihai Florian thank you Sir, very informative

Comment: You're welcome! I forgot to mention that there is plenty of documentation and tutorials online for Objective-C problems. You can find almost any problem you might have answered (even here on Stack Overflow). Swift lacks here. I found myself adapting the Objective-c responses for my Swift problems.